# if and char statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

hello This is not my entire code but I'm stuck at this where I need to print the information only when the user types the word "NewYork" and when I debug nothing is printed even when I type the word "NewYork" . So can anyone one tell what might be the problem? Thanks

```
int main(){

    Panel *panelptr;
    int count,len,wid;
    double heg;
    char locat[30];

    cout<<"how many panels do you need to create ? "<<endl;
    cin>>count;
    panelptr = new Panel[count];
    assert(panelptr!=0);



    for(int i=0; i< count; i++){
        cout << "Enter the length: ";
        cin >>len;
        cout << "Enter the width: ";
        cin >> wid;
        cout << "Enter the height: ";
        cin >> heg;
        cout<<"Enter the location: ";
        cin >>locat;
        panelptr[i].setPanel(len,wid,heg,locat);

        if(locat == "NewYork")
            panelptr->print();

    }


    delete [] panelptr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are comparing the pointer values of the char*, not the actual content. Try using std::string instead of char[]

Comment: This statement `if(locat == "NewYork")` actually compares two `char*` pointers that will never be the same.

Comment: Arrays can't be compared using the `==` operator.   If you insist on comparing `locat` with the string literal "NewYork" (which is represented using an array) look up the `strcmp()` function.   Better yet, use the C++ standard string class (`std::string`) which is specified in the standard header `<string>` instead of an array of `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the char array with a string. Use [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare them:

```
if (strcmp(locat, "NewYork") == 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare char arrays using `if(locat == "NewYork")` like you are. You have two options:

1) Use [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    char locat[30];

    if (strcmp(locat, "NewYork") == 0)
    {
        // Do what you like.
    }
}
```

2) Use [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string locat;

    if (locat == "NewYork")
    {
        // Do what you like.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For string compare you should use `strcmp()` function instead `==`. What you are using is just comparing two `char*` you cannot expect that to be same.
So, change your code from

```
if(locat == "NewYork")
     panelptr->print();
```

To

```
if(strcmp(locat, "NewYork") == 0)
     panelptr->print();
```

`strcmp()` is defined in `string.h` header, So include 
`#include<string.h>` in your program